# Cascading JPA actions other than PERSIST by default

Tags: hibernate, jpa, cascade, spring-orm

How can I cascade JPA actions other than `PERSIST` by default for all attributes, not just those specifically annotated like, e.g., `@OneToOne(cascade = MERGE)`?

This is using the latest versions of Spring ORM on top of JPA on top of Hibernate.

I know that I can persist by default in `orm.xml`, by using:

```
<persistence-unit-metadata>
    <persistence-unit-defaults>
        <cascade-persist/>
```

But there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for actions other than `PERSIST` (i.e. `MERGE`, `REMOVE`, `REFRESH`, `DETACH`)

I'd use any methodology from anywhere in the stack, like:

1. annotations (presumably on packages)
2. XML config files like `persistence.xml`, `orm.xml`, `hibernate.cfg.xml`, etc.
3. Grails 3.1.1 config files like `resources.groovy`, `application.groovy`, etc. (I'm not using GORM, though, just Spring ORM, JPA & Hibernate)

**Consolation Prize Question**

How can I achieve the same effect as `<cascade-persist/>` without `orm.xml`?  Is it possible to configure this via a Spring ORM `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` in `resources.groovy`?